# Permission declared in 'androidManifest.xml', yet still getting permission denial

Tags: android, xml, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm very new to Android/Java development and i've been attempting to build a plugin for Cordova over the past few days and have gotten to the point at which it's executing in my app, however i'm getting this frustrating error in adb logcat whenever I attempt to execute a function:

```
ActivityManager: Permission Denial: Accessing service ComponentInfo{com.kddi.market.validation/com.kddi.market.validation.alml.service.ALMLService} from pid=20745, uid=10336 requires com.kddi.market.permission.USE_ALML
```

The documentation for the library which i'm using states that 'com.kddi.market.permission.USE_ALML' must be included in androidManifest.xml, and so I have:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="30009" android:versionName="3.0.6" package="com.smartpass.asianvalue.skychasers" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.kddi.market.permission.USE_ALML" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

Been at this problem for a few hours now, I'd really appreciate if someone knowledgable could give me some insight into what the problem could be. 
I've seen other people have their problem solved by the inclusion of `android:exported="true"` in their activity but this hadn't worked for me, maybe along a similar line?

I'd also attempted to request permissions on runtime using the following:

```
if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("initClient")) {

    if(cordova.hasPermission("com.kddi.market.permission.USE_ALML")) {
        this.initClient(callbackContext);
    } else {
        cordova.requestPermission(this, 0, "com.kddi.market.permission.USE_ALML");
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: if running on marshmallow and above , are you handling the permission on runtime as well for write and read external storage as well as others stated in manifest.

Comment: I'd attempted to do this, but that was also fruitless, and still returned the same error. Here's how I attempted it:            `if(cordova.hasPermission("com.kddi.market.permission.USE_ALML")) {
                this.initClient(callbackContext);
            } else {
                cordova.requestPermission(this, 0, "com.kddi.market.permission.USE_ALML");
            }`

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution, the permission wasn't being defined before it was used. I've never seen anyone have to use custom permissions like this before, and it also seems kind of redundant to have to define and set permissions right next to each other.

Instead of my 'androidManifest.xml' only having:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.kddi.market.permission.USE_ALML" />
```

I needed:

```
<permission android:name="com.kddi.market.permission.USE_ALML" />
```

put before it.

weird.